# Dock and Desktop icons disappeared after disk error on 20.04 (with dual boot Windows 10)

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, icons, dock

My laptop has a habit of shutting down with hard disk errors. After one such error, when I restarted the laptop, the dock and desktop icons had disappeared. I tried `sudo-apt-install-gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock` but it said that the dock was latest and `0 upgraded, 0 installed`.

There is no "new folder" option when I right click on the desktop. I tried putting a new file in the desktop folder, but the icons did not reappear. I also tried <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>r</kbd>, but with no success.

Comment: Fix your HDD before fixing the desktop? `fsck` disk utility can (usually) fix filesystem inconsistencies, while a `SMART` disk test (available e.g. through the _Disks_ app) can find hardware-level disk problems. First of all however back up all your important files.

Comment: I have used fsck twice till now and it has worked temporarily. Let me get back to you after trying the smart dick thingy.
edit- Read error rate, Spinup time, Reallocated sector count, Seek error rate, Spinup Retry count, Head-flying hours are all pre-fail. Others are old-age. Overall assessment-Disk is OK, 32288 bad sectors

Comment: It is time to replace the hard drive. Every time it fails and you have to power off without a proper shut down you have the possibility of damage to the file system.

Comment: Okay. Also, should I replace it with an SSD instead?

Answer (score 0):

I installed dash to dock and that solved the dock problem, but the icons problem still persists